# Is there a way to tell if data points are independent by looking at a the graph?

Tags: independence

[Scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0t5z.jpg)

Say I have a scatterplot like the one above. Is there an easy way to determine whether or not the x and y values are independent from one another just by looking at the way the plots are placed on the graph? Or would I have to do mathematical computation to determine that? I can see that they are uncorrelated because there is no linear relationship between x and y but I dont know about independence...

Comment: Link doesn't work for me. Try using imgur or something similar.

Comment: @Lovsovs sorry about that. does this work?

Comment: What definition are you using of "independent"? Because typically, independent refers to a process for generating data points, rather than the data points themselves.

Comment: @GregMartin guess Im just trying to see if there is some sort of pattern visually that can tell whether or not the data points were generated independently from each other but the more I think about it, the more I am convincing myself that thats a little illogical. Was just a thought I had earlier in the day and I couldnt find anything online that told me anything.